# How can I verify that web pages are being gzipped?

Tags: weblogic, gzip, gzipstream

I plan to configure weblogic's gzip servlet filter (using weblogicx-gzip.jar) to gzip my web pages.

How can I verify that the pages are being sent to the client gzipped?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Install [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.
2. Enable FireBug.
3. Enable the *Net* tab.
4. Load your webpage.
5. Expand the line that contains your webpage.
6. If `Content-Encoding` is `gzip` you received the page in GZip format.

Comment: I don't see "Content-Encoding". I see "Transfer-Encoding". Is that the one I should look at?

Comment: never mind, once i successfully configured gzip, the content-encoding: gzip now shows up

Answer (score 4):

I second the Yslow comment. But to expand just a little, YSlow will show items are using GZip as well as items that are not. Just go to the Components tab of the YSlow Plugin and it will give you a nice column view of items (see image).

[image: YSlow Components Tab]

Comment: Thanks for the update on YSlow having this capability. I dont think it had this 2 years ago when I asked this question. :)

Answer (score 1):

yslow will tell you. At least it will tell you when they are not zipped.

Answer (score 1):

Fast and easy for you: Check online on below sites:

1. http://checkgzipcompression.com/
2. http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/

Hope it useful

Answer (score 0):

that site offer online tool to check

http://www.port80software.com/products/httpzip/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for a automatic way. But the Firebug and/or PageSpeed extensions for Firefox will tell which files are being gzipped.

For Firebug, in the "Net" panel, if you look at the files headers there should be a "Content-Encoding: gzip" header if it's gzipped.

The YSlow extension will also tell you on one screen which JS/CSS files are gzipped and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and inspect the http header for gzip encoding. Also if you want to see how much compression it did, you can see the page size with and without the filter. From my experience I have seen 90% compression on average on text data.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome's, or Chromium's, web developer kit can also do this (in a similar fashion as Firebug).