# How to tell if ob_gzhandler is working?

Tags: php, compression, ob-start

How can I check to see if

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

is working and test the difference with or without it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "Net" tab of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), check to see if the `Content-Encoding` header has a value of `gzip` or `deflate`.

Or, try the [online gzip test](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php).

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428542/how-can-i-verify-that-web-pages-are-being-gzipped).

Comment: We can test the HTTP Compression also [*here*](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ob_list_handlers`](http://php.net/ob_list_handlers) to get an array of handlers that are in use.